# Is there any syntax followed for naming <servlet-class>

Tags: java, servlets

This is a example global-web.xml file

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>ExampleInitServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>test.example.ExampleInitServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
  <param-name>testname</param-name>
  <param-value>Test</param-value>
  <description>
  </description>
  </init-param>
</servlet>
```

In  they have defined a name test.example.ExampleInitServlet. I understood that test is the param-value and ExampleInitServlet is servlet name. What is "example" in the servlet-class name definition. Is there any syntax format which needs to be followed for defining .

Comment: actually **test.example** is package name
please check this
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Answer (score 1):

`test.example` is the fully qualified package name that contains the ExampleInitServlet class.